# SD card in SDIO is not working in latest CubeIDE

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4, fatfs

Im trying to connect sd card in sdio to stm32f407vg discovery to store some data. Im using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NbBem8U80Y. Im doing everything step by step, but it is still not working. This is my code.

```
#include "main.h"
#include "fatfs.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
SD_HandleTypeDef hsd;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SDIO_SD_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
FATFS myFatFS;
FIL myFile;
UINT myBytes;
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SDIO_SD_Init();
  MX_FATFS_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  if(f_mount(&myFatFS,SDPath,1) == FR_OK)
   {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET);//green
        char myFileName[] = "TEST1.txt";
        if (f_open(&myFile, myFileName, FA_WRITE | FA_CREATE_ALWAYS) == FR_OK)
            {
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);//orange
                char myData[] = "Hello from STM32F4 Disco, SDIO in 4 bits mode";
                if (f_write(&myFile, myData, sizeof(myData), &myBytes))
                    {
                                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);//blue

                    }
                    f_close(&myFile);
            }
   }
   else
  {
                                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);//red

  }
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 192;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief SDIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SDIO_SD_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDIO_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SDIO_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDIO_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SDIO_Init 1 */
  hsd.Instance = SDIO;
  hsd.Init.ClockEdge = SDIO_CLOCK_EDGE_RISING;
  hsd.Init.ClockBypass = SDIO_CLOCK_BYPASS_DISABLE;
  hsd.Init.ClockPowerSave = SDIO_CLOCK_POWER_SAVE_DISABLE;
  hsd.Init.BusWide = SDIO_BUS_WIDE_1B;
  hsd.Init.HardwareFlowControl = SDIO_HARDWARE_FLOW_CONTROL_DISABLE;
  hsd.Init.ClockDiv = 0;
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDIO_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SDIO_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PD12 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PD13 PD14 PD15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

After uploading this code to my STM the red LED starts to light. The returning value of f_mount is not equal to FR_OK. I checked all connections, they are correct. Please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the value `hsd.Init.ClockDiv = 3` for example.
It is better to use 4 bit, but there is a bug in HAL for this mode. If needed, I'll tell you how to fix it.